# Repeated Scene items in iOS YUV video capturing output

Tags: iphone, ios, video, yuv, color-space

I capture a video and handle the resulting YUV frames.
the output looks like the following: 
[image: Sample from the resulting video]

Although it appears normally on my phone's screen. But my peer receives it like that img above.
Every item is repeated and shifted by some value horizontally and vertically

My captured video is 352x288 and my YPixelCount = 101376, UVPixelCount = YPIXELCOUNT/4

Any clue to solve this or a starting point to understand how to handle YUV video frames on iOS ?

```
    NSNumber* recorderValue = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange];
    [videoRecorderSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288];
```

> And this is the captureOutput function

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
    if(CMSampleBufferIsValid(sampleBuffer) && CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer) && ([self isQueueStopped] == FALSE))
    {

        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0); 
        UInt8 *baseAddress[3] = {NULL,NULL,NULL};
        uint8_t *yPlaneAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer,0);
        UInt32 yPixelCount =  CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBuffer,0) * CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBuffer,0);
        uint8_t *uvPlaneAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer,1);
        UInt32 uvPixelCount = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBuffer,1) * CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBuffer,1);
        UInt32  p,q,r;
        p=q=r=0;
        memcpy(uPointer, uvPlaneAddress, uvPixelCount);
        memcpy(vPointer, uvPlaneAddress+uvPixelCount, uvPixelCount);

        memcpy(yPointer,yPlaneAddress,yPixelCount);
        baseAddress[0] = (UInt8*)yPointer;
        baseAddress[1] = (UInt8*)uPointer;
        baseAddress[2] = (UInt8*)vPointer;
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    }
}
```

> Is there anything wrong with the above code ?

Comment: Please show your code. It seems that you don't properly compute the start address of the planes and that you probably also misunderstood where and how the UV color information (as opposed to the Y luminance information) is stored.

Comment: Yes, this looks like what you'd expect from a misreading of either YUV planar or interleaved data.  What exactly is your input format (YUV420P, etc.)? How are you writing that to an image to send to your peer?

Comment: @Codo Thanks for your comment. I added code snippets in the question.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for your comment. I added code snippets in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't look to0 bad. I can see two mistakes and one potential problem:

- The `uvPixelCount` is incorrect. The YUV 420 format means that there is color information for each 2 by 2 pixel block. So the correct count is:

  ```
  uvPixelCount = (width / 2) * (height / 2);
  ```

  You write something about `yPixelCount / 4`, but I cannot see that in your code.
- The UV information is interleaved, i.e. the second plane alternatingly contains a U and a V value. Or put differently: there's a U value on all even byte addresses and a V value on all odd byte addresses. If you really need to separate the U and V information, `memcpy` won't do.
- There can be some extra bytes after each pixel row. You should use `CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)` to get the number of bytes between two rows. As a consequence, a single `memcpy` won't do. Instead you need to copy each pixel row separately to get rid of the extra bytes between the rows.

All these things only explain part of the resulting image. The remaining parts are probably due to differences between your code and what the receiving peer expect. You did't write anything about that? Does the peer really need separated U and V values? Does it you 4:2:0 compression as well? Does it you video range instead of full range as well?

If you provide more information, I can give your more hints.

Comment: point 1: `CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBuffer,1) * CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBuffer,1) = (1/4)CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBuffer,0) * CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBuffer,0);`
while debugging yPixelCount = 101376 while uvPixelCount = 25344


.. **BTW**:when i commented the UV parts i got grayScale video with the same repeated items. very same to the above but grayScale ones

Comment: Indeed, your pixel count is most likely correct. I've missed an important detail in your code. Regarding the repeated items: There's obviously a mismatch between what you send and what your peer expects. But without more code and more information, we can't help you.

Comment: Both `CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)`  and  `CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1)` return 352 while using the `AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288`